# Prepopulate a lookup field when the new button is pressed

Tags: json, url, urlhacking, lookup-field

I am trying to prepopulate a lookup field when the user presses the "New" button. This object is in the related list of another object. Those two objects are part of a managed package.  The ui i'm using is a visualforce, the related list is also contained in that visualforce. All the actions made in the ui are done through json. What i am trying to do is this:

```
/a1m/e?CF00N0Q000001sKYB=@@BASKETNAME@@&CF00N0Q000001sKYB_lkid=@@BASKETID@@&RecordType=0122X000000KWpwQAG&retURL= %2F@@BASKETID@@#@@CONTEXT@@
```

Based on the managed package's documentation the:

@@BASKETNAME@@ = provides the current basket's name (basket is the parent object)
@@BASKETID@@ = provides the current basket's id

@@CONTEXT@@ = the current context; this will be either "apex" or the current community prefix

In their documentation there is an example regarding cases:

```
"/500/e?CF00Nw0000006lix8=@@BASKETNAME@@&CF00Nw0000006lix8_lkid=@@BASKETID@@&retURL
=%2F@@BASKETID@@#@@CONTEXT@@",
```

Although i follow the instructions but also some guides i found online i can't prepopulate the lookup field i need to.

Any ideas about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer so i'm replying to my own post in case it helps someone else.
What i have posted concerns the classic salesforce and not the lightning. In order to accomplish my goal for lightning i used this:

```
lightning/o/Agreement__c/new?recordtypeid=0122X000000KWpwQAG&defaultFieldValues=Basket__c=@@BASKETID@@&retURL= %2F@@BASKETID@@#@@CONTEXT@@
```